# women killers vs. woman killers

Tags: attributive-nouns

a. woman killers

b. women killers

---

c. woman-killers

d. women-killers

Which of the above mean

1. people who kill women (I suppose technically a woman can kill women too)
2. women who kill
   ?

I think (a) and (c) are ambiguous and (b) and (d) mean women who kill.

Many thanks

Comment: I don't think any of those forms is unambiguous without context.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think we would be likely to use any of these forms (as SoronelHaetir mentions) precisely because they're ambiguous.

Comment: If you want to talk about a **Singular** woman who kills , try "killer woman" (with or without hyphen) & **Plural** "killer-women" , which is in line with "Police men" , not "men-Police" in general. With that line of thought , I go with B&D to mean those who kill women ["There is a gang of women killers in town : Women are advised to not go out at night" ] , whereas A&C talk about those who try to kill (or succeeded in killing) a Single unfortunate woman , though it is strange [ "Murder victim was a woman in her twenties : Investigators are looking for witnesses who saw the woman-killers" ]

Answer (score 6):

I would tend to select "female killers" for the case of talking about the class of killers that are female/women rather than any of the provided options.

As for specifying the case of killers that target women I would probably rearrange the terms (as done in this sentence) rather than trying to use a reduced form, the reduced forms just sound/read awkward to me.

Comment: Perhaps femicide might work https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Femicide although that is usually the crime not the perpetrator.

Answer (score 3):

Without a context, none of your suggestions unambiguously mean a person who murders women.

"People who kill women" or "Murderers who target women" are unambiguous and natural.